# How to save array of objects in mongodb with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save complex data, ie array of objects to mongoose. I have tried few things but i couldn't save the data.

I defined my schema as above and i want to save array of objects that could have any level of nesting.
**Schema**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose);
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post: [{}]
});

let PostModel = mongoose.Model('Post', PostSchema)
```

**The Data:**
[image]

Here is the code I used to **save the data**

```js
app.post('/saveData, async (req, res) => {
    const response = await Post.create(req.body);
    res.json({
        data: response
    });
});

app.listen(8008, () => {
    console.log('server running);
});
```

The problem is that i cant retrieve the data. it returns array of objects equal to the number of saved array but with no data in it.

How can it be done?

Comment: please add code instead of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.

```
  const PostModel =  require('./Post');    //declare your model
  app.post('/saveData', async (req, res) => {
    const objModel = new PostModel();
    objModel.post = req.body;   //assign the data post array.
    const response = await objModel.save();
    res.json({
      data: response
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post schema looks weird.
You have a collection for Posts and then within a posts schema, you have a posts array.
What is the point of that?
The post collection already is an "array" for posts.

```
// Perhaps you are looking for something like this.
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    level: Number,
    footer: String,
    author: ObjectId,// who wrote the post
    comments: [{
       user: ObjectId,
       comment: String
    }],
    ... createdAt, updatedAt etc
});
```

Your data structure doesnt seem to match your schema either.
e.g
await Post.create({posts: req.body});

Comment: The only control i have over the data to be saved is that it is the array of object. I am using WYSIWYG editor(editorjs) to write a post. So having schema defined like that wouldnt work for me. Solution answered worked as intended for me!!